# Test-Connection output in realtime without spacing

Tags: powershell, format, output

```
Test-Connection PCNAME -count 6 | ft address, ipv4address, responsetime
```

I am trying to write a command to test the connection (ping) a device using the above command, however, when I run this, it outputs huge spacing in between each column. I can always add `-AutoSize` to the end of that command, but then the output doesn't show on the screen until it is finished, which defeats the purpose of the command. Is there a way to output results in realtime without spacing?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me.  You just have to give `format-table` some widths that are more appropriate:

```
try {
Test-Connection blah -count 6 -ErrorAction Stop | ft @{Name='address';Expr={$_.address};width=10},
                                        @{Name='ipv4address';Expr={$_.ipv4address};width=12},
                                        @{Name='responsetime';Expr={$_.responsetime};width=15} 

} catch [System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException]  {
  write-output 'request timed out'
}
```

Edit: added try/catch for response timed out.

Comment: Do you know of a way to mimic the "Request Timed out" feature of regular ping? If it pings, then doesnt during the run, display "timed out" ?

Comment: It won't work like you're suggesting, though, with failure in the middle.  It will just stop when it times out.

Answer (score 1):

No there's no way to do this. As you've discovered, `AutoSize` requires all the items in order to work out the size of the columns and then does the rendering.

As you're just pinging the connection is the formatting of the table that much of a concern?

NOTE: You could always format the output yourself using `ForEach-Object` to make it look a bit more ping-esque:

```
Test-Connection PCNAME -count 6 | % {Write-Host "Reply from $($_.IPV4Address): bytes=$($_.BufferSize) time=$($_.ResponseTime) TTL=$($_.ResponseTimeToLive)"}
```

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to combine it into a tool for use at work, and when troubleshooting PC's with connection issues, seeing the ping in real time is a requirement.

Comment: @Aaron - I've added an example of how to use `Test-Connection` to give a more ping like output